# bringSubview(toFront:) seems not working

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following layout.
[image]

What I am trying to achieve is make the yellow subview as circle and bring it to front. I tried `self.view.bringSubview(toFront:yellowView)` but seems not working as I expected. How can I fix this?

-- edit
Sorry for the lack of details.

So on the root view, I have two subviews, top section and bottom section.
The bottom section is empty for now but the top section contains an imageview with same size as the top section and an circle UIView.

So what I want is to bring the bottom part os the circle UIView to front.

Comment: Is your yellow view a subview of view or the imageView?

Comment: @vacawama There is a container view that includes both image view and the circle view. I just set image view as same size as its parent view.

Comment: You need to provide more detail... What code is generating the Circle? What is the view hierarchy? Are the circle, yellow square and image view all subviews of a single UIView? Or all individual views? What's the gray rectangle? Another view? Tough to help if you don't explain what you have...

Comment: Did you check using view hierarchy?

Comment: @DonMag editted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that the circle `UIView` is not a child of the root view, but a child of the top view.  In order for the circle to appear in front of the bottom view, reorder your view hierarchy.

Make the circle `UIView` a child of the root view.  Then you will be able to bring it to the front of the other views with the code you have shown.  In fact, if you make the circle `UIView` the last child of the root view, it will appear in front of all of the subviews of the root view.

*Desired View Hierarchy:*

```
Root View
    - Top View
        - UIImageView
    - Bottom View
    - Circle View
```

---

In the *Document Outline*, drag the *Circle View* and drop it onto the *Root View*.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But do you know why the previous attempt did not work? even if I set clipsToBound to false?

Comment: Yes.  The bottom view was in front of the top view and all of its children.  Since it didn't cover the top view, the UIImage showed, but the circle which extended into the bottom area was covered by the bottom view.

Comment: So, you could have brought the top view to the front of the root view, and then the circle view to the front of the top view.  But, I still think it is best for the circle view to have the root view as its parent.

Comment: Perfect. I agree that your solution is right one. Thanks million times.

Answer (score 2):

If Your `circleView` and `imageView` is `subview` of `containerView`
then try this code.

```
self.containerView.bringSubview(toFront:yellowView)
```

Comment: Can you look at my edited original question? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Set clipBounds property to false for UIImageView:

```
self.imageView.clipsToBounds = false
```

Comment: This is not working? One thing I did not mention in the question is that there is container view that includes both image view and the circle view. I tried both container view and image view set clipsToBounds false and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You must call bringSubview from its superview. 
try this;

self.yellowView.superview?.bringSubview(toFront: self.yellowView)

you can add outlet for yellowView.superview if you want.